# No such library ssl, telethon

Tags: python, python-3.x, telethon

I have got error when using python 3.7 telethon.
error below:

`i use logging: INFO:telethon.crypto.libssl:Failed to load SSL library: <class 'OSError'> (no library called "ssl" found) INFO:telethon.crypto.aes:cryptg detected, it will be used for encryption`

i have already installed cryptg

Comment: Can you share some code

Comment: Same here, could you resolve it?

Comment: @itsAPK the error is raised by simply importing ssl, which gives no error, then any one of the modules in telethon. For instance: ```import ssl; from telethon.errors import SessionPasswordNeededError```, ```from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync, utils, functions```, ```from telethon.tl.types import (PeerChannel, PeerUser)```, and ```from telethon.tl.functions.messages import (GetHistoryRequest)``` all exhibit the same behaviour